# echo password to screen as *'s from variable with bash

Tags: bash

I have a script that accepts a username and password or uses pre-set variables. I want to echo this info to the user so they know it is set, but don't want to display the actual password.

How can I print the correct number of *'s instead of the password?

Comment: This link shows you how you can get the string length. http://bashrules.blogspot.com/2005/04/strlen-of-bash.html

Comment: Why do you want to give an indication of the password actual length? why not just output `*********`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print your password as string of `*` you can do:

```
echo $passwd | sed -e 's/./*/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `read` command with a -s option.

Comment: This isn't what he is referring to. This will only prevent users to see what they are typing when they feed the value to the variable. If you echo the variable it will still show the value.

Comment: As Jaypal said... when my script runs the password is already known, so I needed to just echo it out...

Answer (score 1):

**AWK Solution 1:**

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ echo "password" | awk '{a=length($0); for (i=1;i<=a;i++) printf "*"}'
********
```

**AWK Solution 2:**

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ echo "password" | awk '{gsub(/./,"*",$0); print}'
********
```

Answer (score 0):

like, if password stored in variable `pawd` then

```
for((i=1;i<=(${#pawd});i++));do printf "%s" "*";done;printf "\n"
```

Comment: This works but the version I accepted was the one I used as it was more understandable for me... thanks though!

Answer (score -1):

If the visible character must not be '*', then a simple in shell pattern substitution will do the job

```
echo ${password//?/+}
```

An asterisk instead of the plus sign will lead to prblem with shell expansions. Escaping the asterisk with backslashes wont ginbt the proper result.

The advantage if the in shell pattern substitution is that there is no external program to pipe through.